# Json class definition, is my structure correct for deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

I trying to dezilirze some json into my class I used the tool at http://json2csharp.com/ to transform the json request from the following

```
{
    "movie_details": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "movie 1",
        "description": "movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n\r\nmovie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1movie 1\r\n",
        "image": "http://popcorn.pk/img/Movie/harley3.jpg",
        "secondry_images": "movie/Jellyfish.jpg,movie/Koala.jpg,movie/Jellyfish.jpg",
        "actor": "anandan",
        "actoress": "anandan",
        "director": "anandan",
        "music_director": "anandan",
        "release_date": "March 18, 2015",
        "tags": "movie 1,movie 1 ",
        "age_restriction": "14",
        "box_office": "36985214",
        "official_site": "http://google.com",
        "duration": "1.50 hr",
        "writers": "anandan",
        "imdb": 8,
        "status": "1",
        "language": "Tamil",
        "created": "2015-03-11 05:11:31",
        "modified": "2015-03-25 10:12:39",
        "movie_category_id": "Action",
        "slug": "movie 1 ",
        "movie_show_time_id": "0",
        "theatre_movie_screen_id": "0",
        "videous": "",
        "videos": "",
        "comming_soon": "0",
        "avg": 0,
        "movie_details_url": "http://popcorn.pk/launch/Movies/view/1"
    },
    "fetch_timing": [
        {
            "id": "23",
            "theater_name": "SUPER CINEMA - ROYAL PALM",
            "address": "Royal Palm Golf and Country Club, 52 Canal Bank road, Lahore",
            "show_times": [
                "4:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "28",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "24",
            "theater_name": "SOZO WORLD CINEMA",
            "address": "Fortress Stadium, Lahore - Cantt, Lahore, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "2:30 pm",
                "7:30 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "29",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "25",
            "theater_name": "ATRIUM CINEMA",
            "address": "3rd Floor, Atrium Mall, 249 Staff Lines, Zaibunnisa Street, Saddar. Karachi, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "5:15 pm",
                "11:30 am"
            ],
            "screen_id": "30",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "26",
            "theater_name": "UNIVERSE CINEPLEX",
            "address": "55-C, Khayaban-e-Muslim, Muslim Commercial Area Phase 6, D.H.A. Karachi, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "3:30 pm",
                "9:30 pm",
                "6:30 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "31",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "27",
            "theater_name": "CINEPAX - OCEAN MALL",
            "address": "Cinepax, Ocean Tower, 2 Sword, Clifton, Karachi",
            "show_times": [
                "5:45 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "32",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "28",
            "theater_name": "CINEPAX - CITY AUDITORIUM",
            "address": "Opposite Meezan Bank Regional Office at Ayesha Manzil, FB Area Block 14,Karachi,Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "3:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "33",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "29",
            "theater_name": "NUEPLEX",
            "address": "The Place, Khayaban e Shaheen Phase 8, D.H.A",
            "show_times": [
                "6:15 pm",
                "3:10 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "34",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "theater_name": "CENTAURUS CINEPLEX",
            "address": "Centaurus Mall, 1 Jinnah Avenue, 4th Floor Centaurus, F-8 Islamabad",
            "show_times": [
                "8:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "35",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "31",
            "theater_name": "THE ARENA",
            "address": "The Arena, Rawapindi, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "8:30 pm",
                "5:45 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "36",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "theater_name": "CINE MOOSH",
            "address": "House no. A/18, Unit no.3, Main AutoBhan Road, Latifabad, Hyderabad",
            "show_times": [
                "3:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "37",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "33",
            "theater_name": "CINEGOLD PLEX",
            "address": "Main Boulevard, Garden City, between Phase 7 & 8, Expressway, Rawalpindi 46000",
            "show_times": [
                "7:45 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "38",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "34",
            "theater_name": "CINEPAX JINNAH PARK",
            "address": "Cinepax Jinnah Park Kachehri Road, Rawalpindi 00e220ac201c Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "12:00 pm",
                "8:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "39",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "35",
            "theater_name": "CINEPAX HOTEL ONE",
            "address": "Hotel One 99/C, Peoples Colony (Near D Ground) Faisalabad",
            "show_times": [
                "3:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "40",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "36",
            "theater_name": "SUPER CINEMA",
            "address": "Vogue Tower, MM Alam road, Lahore",
            "show_times": [
                "2:15 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "41",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "38",
            "theater_name": "CINE STAR",
            "address": "Plot #13,2 civic center township Lahore",
            "show_times": [
                "7:15 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "43",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "39",
            "theater_name": "TAJ CINEMA",
            "address": "Plot #13,2 civic center township Lahore",
            "show_times": [
                "2:00 pm",
                "10:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "44",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "40",
            "theater_name": "CINESTAR IMAX",
            "address": "Plot #13,2 civic center township Lahore",
            "show_times": [
                "2:00 pm",
                "7:30 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "45",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "41",
            "theater_name": "Taj Mahal Multiplex",
            "address": "Taj Mahal Multiplex Cinemas, Railway Road, Faisalabad-38000",
            "show_times": [
                "4:00 pm",
                "10:00 pm",
                "7:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "46",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "42",
            "theater_name": "The Arena Orchard",
            "address": "Phase 1 Baharia Orchard Raiwind Road, Lahore, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "11:15 pm",
                "11:00 am"
            ],
            "screen_id": "47",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "44",
            "theater_name": "DHA Cinema",
            "address": "305-R Block, D.H.A, Lahore Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "5:00 pm",
                "10:30 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "49",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "45",
            "theater_name": "Cinepax Fortress",
            "address": "2nd Floor, Fortress Square Shopping Mall, Lahore - Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "8:15 pm",
                "10:45 pm",
                "2:30 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "50",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "47",
            "theater_name": "Imperial Cinemas",
            "address": "Imperial Garden Homes, Lahore, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "2:30 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "52",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "48",
            "theater_name": "CINEPAX GUJRANWALA",
            "address": "Prince Cinepax Main G T Road, Gujranwala - Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "8:45 pm",
                "5:45 pm",
                "6:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "53",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "49",
            "theater_name": "Super Cinema - Gujrat",
            "address": "Super Cinema Gujrat, Gt Road, Gujrat",
            "show_times": [
                "1:00 pm",
                "10:00 pm",
                "7:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "54",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "50",
            "theater_name": "PAF Cinema",
            "address": "Sarfaraz Rafiqui Road, Lahore, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "3:00 pm",
                "11:00 pm",
                "2:00 am"
            ],
            "screen_id": "55",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        },
        {
            "id": "51",
            "theater_name": "Capri Cinema",
            "address": "Gazdarabad, Karachi, Pakistan, Karachi, Pakistan",
            "show_times": [
                "6:00 pm"
            ],
            "screen_id": "56",
            "title": "Standard Screen"
        }
    ]
}
```

But for some reason i hitting a deubugger error on process of thie list. My GetMovieDetailAysnc is working bringing back the text fine for the json string.

```
public async Task<List<MovieDetail>> GetMovieDetailsList(int movieId)
{
        string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");
        var list = jsonresult.Deserialize<MovieDetails>();
        return list.movieDetaillist;
}
```

But My error occourse on the deserilize method the class for movie details is as follows

```
 public class MovieDetails
 {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string secondry_images { get; set; }
        public string actor { get; set; }
        public string actoress { get; set; }
        public string director { get; set; }
        public string music_director { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
        public string age_restriction { get; set; }
        public string box_office { get; set; }
        public string official_site { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public string writers { get; set; }
        public int imdb { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string created { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string movie_category_id { get; set; }
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string movie_show_time_id { get; set; }
        public string theatre_movie_screen_id { get; set; }
        public string videous { get; set; }
        public string videos { get; set; }
        public string comming_soon { get; set; }
        public int avg { get; set; }
        public string movie_details_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class FetchTiming
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string theater_name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public List<string> show_times { get; set; }
        public string screen_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDetail
    {
        public MovieDetails movie_details { get; set; }
        public List<FetchTiming> fetch_timing { get; set; }
    }
```

}

My question is what could be cuasing the error I am at a loss here as the data is valid.My Deserlize method is as below

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this string SerializedJSONString)
{
        var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(SerializedJSONString);
        return stuff;
}
```

**Edit Notes**

To Futher investaget this i am getting the error on this

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[popcornpk.DataModel.MovieDetails]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: and why a mark down a wonder who it is this time !

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you mention an error, it would be helpful to give details on **what** error it is, and **exactly** what line you get it on.

Comment: it just brakes on the is debugger attached error no specific error givin

Comment: The debugger doesn't just break for no reason, do you have a breakpoint set there?

Comment: I didn't downvote, because it seems to be valid question, but my inner grammar nazi seems to be displeased with this decision. Jokes aside, it is hard to say what is wrong if we do not know why it is wrong, eq. what kind of exception is thrown, what data(if any) is returned from functions etc.

Comment: It seems to me that you are actually trying to deserialize a `List<MovieDetail>`, when the test data you gave just contains a **single** `MovieDetail`. The deserialization itself [runs perfectly fine](http://csharppad.com/gist/2049ca31b4b4d624107d). However, there is no such member as `movieDetaillist` in `MovieDetails`, so your code should not even compile.

Comment: Also, your `async` method accepts an `int`, yet does nothing with it... Did you mean to pass it to the service?

Comment: above is the error message and no im just retreieving the default for now for the method

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you pass the wrong type to `Deserialize` method – not `MovieDetail`, but `MovieDetails` (in case I properly understand that your WCF service returns single instance) and use wrong type for generic `Task` result. So just try updating `GetMovieDetailsList(int movieId)` method with the following code (including signature):

```
public async Task<MovieDetail> GetMovieDetailsList(int movieId)
{
    string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "movie_details");
    var details = jsonresult.Deserialize<MovieDetail>();
    return details;
}
```